# Two foreign keys, only one can be not null at a time

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I have a database table with two foreign keys pointing to two different tables. The business logic requires an "either or" relationship; only one foreign key can be NOT NULL at any given time.

Here are the four possible states the foreign keys can hold based on the business logic:

- NULL, NULL - okay
- number, NULL - okay
- NULL, number - okay
- number, number - **invalid business logic**

I'm using Django, and I know I can write some onSave() checks that will handle this, but that feels hackish.

Is there a better method to deal with this business logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_table_fk1_fk2 on table
    check (fk1 is null or fk2 is null);
```

Comment: Thanks, from this I found this link which nicely solves the situation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/